# How does Microsoft Bot Service Provision Skype bot

Tags: botframework, skype-bots

Would like to know how Microsoft Bot Service Provision Skype bot , Need to check the underline code how microsoft bot service is using Skype API to create skype bot. Please provide the reference and source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you are asking for is not open source. Bot Framework has many pieces open source (like the [SDKs](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder), the [Emulator](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator), the [WebChat control](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) among others) but the piece you are asking is not.

I suspect you have another issue; so I would recommend either to post a new question with the specific problem or clarify this one.

If you want to learn how Skype works with BotFramework, pleas read https://dev.skype.com/bots.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for? You need to use the Bot Framework tooling, eg. the BotBuilder Nuget package if you are using C# or the botbuilder npm package in node.

Comment: This is the answer of the question. The code he asking is not open source and so cannot be shared.

Comment: ok fine @EzequielJadib code is not open source fine.  Basically , we were  looking for some documentation or code  talking about provisioning of Skype bot using microsoft bot service.

Comment: No, it does not talk anything about provisioning of skype bot. it leads me to botframework about which we already know. So Skype bots can be created only through microsoft bot service. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: So you want to create a bot for skype, without using Bot Framework, that's the question?

Comment: yes, without registering the bot with dev.botframework.com/bots link